# Value of EditText not appearing in my logs

Tags: java, android

I an new to Android.  I have the following code for a Twitter Client search:

```
package com.michaelnares.twitterclient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by michael on 01/05/2014.
 */
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    EditText queryEditText = null;
    String queryText = null;
    private Context context = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        queryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.queryEditText);
        queryText = (queryEditText.getText().toString());
        final Context context = this;

        Button queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.queryButton);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i(LogConstants.LOG, "Text value is " + queryText);
                if (queryText.equals(null)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You did not enter a query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    new SearchAsyncTask().execute();
                    }
            }
        });
    } // ends onCreate()

    private class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>>
    {

       private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);
        private ArrayList<String> searchResults;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("Getting data...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            APIClient client = new APIClient();
            searchResults = client.getQueryResults(queryText);
            return searchResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> results)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            results.addAll(searchResults);
            if (searchResults == null)
            {
                Log.w(LogConstants.LOG, "searchResults is null");
            }
            final ListView searchListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchListView);
            final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            searchListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
} //ends class
```

The issue is, I have tried to log the results of the EditText, however I never see that in the logs.  What is going on here?  I can't work out why I'm never seeing "Text value is " + queryText in the logs.

Comment: An unrelated note `queryText.equals(null)` to `"".equals(queryText)` because if `queryText` is really a null then this will crash `null.equals` will give null pointer exception

Comment: @ShereefMarzouk If he's trying to test for `null`, the correct code would be `if(queryText == null)`.

Comment: @shmosel he is trying to test for an empty string hence his message `"You did not enter a query"`

Comment: @shmosel it will never be null because getText never returns null anyway iirc

Comment: @ShereefMarzouk That may be the case, but it's unrelated to the potential `NullPointerException` you correctly pointed out.

Comment: true :) the correct fix for null check would be what you wrote ^_^ but I wrote what would be useful in his case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you initialize the String value queryText in the event of the screen being created (onCreate()) and not when you actually type in values (after screen creation & dynamic activity on the screen).

This is why the following would work

```
     @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
 queryText = (queryEditText.getText().toString());
                    Log.i(LogConstants.LOG, "Text value is " + queryText);
                    if (queryText.equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "You did not enter a query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        new SearchAsyncTask().execute();
                        }
                }
```

Comment: What you wrote will create problems for him in the async task since it doesn't update the queryText variable which is used there

Comment: It had nothing to do with the question, but yes I'll edit with fix anyways.

Comment: Is one of you able to clarify what alterations I would have to make to the AsyncTask to make that work?

Comment: OK, that's solved that issue, but it's still not returning anything back from the API, which baffles me.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 Log.i(LogConstants.LOG, "Text value is " + queryText);
```

to

```
 Log.i(LogConstants.LOG, "Text value is " + queryEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Nope, hasn't made any difference.

Comment: this is totally wrong there is no `getText` for type `String` as i recall

Comment: queryEditText hat type EditText. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Move 
        `queryText = (queryEditText.getText().toString());`

inside the onClick

```
    queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            queryText = (queryEditText.getText().toString());
            Log.i(LogConstants.LOG, "Text value is " + queryText);
            if ("".equals(queryText)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You did not enter a query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                new SearchAsyncTask().execute();
                }
        }
    });
```